# I am not able to browse doc, pdf file ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I am creating hybrid mobile app (ionic framework) where i want to upload resume from android mobile and send it to remote server. But i am getting problem to browse or select doc file from mobile. I have tried with cordova-plugin-mfilechooser, com.megster.cordova.FileChooser. But I am able to browse pic from mobile gallery and upload it to remote server.

Thanks in advance.

Narendra

Comment: Use file Transfer Plugin https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/

Comment: i recently tried com.megster.cordova.FileChooser plugin and its working.

Comment: Hi Navneeth, I am not able to install com.megster.cordova.FileChooser plugin. Can u plz send me sample code.